# Using PLS to determine relative contributions of different drivers to the variability of a source?

Tags: regression, python, scikit-learn, vector-autoregression, partial-least-squares

I have a several drivers that are influencing the variability of a source. The drivers are not independent of one another, so I cannot use linear regression. Instead, I used Partial Least Squares (PLS) in order to determine the relative contributions of these different drivers to the source variability.If I were using linear regression, I could simply fit A * D1 + B * D2 + C * D3 to my SOURCE. (DX are the drivers, A,B,C are the coefficients that I am fitting.) Then, A**2 would be roughly equivalent to the contribution of D1 to SOURCE variability.In terms of PLR, I can also extract coefficients (I am using the python package sklearn) like so:

```
from sklearn.cross_decomposition import PLSRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
import numpy as np

X = np.column_stack((D1, D2, D3))

X_train, X_test, SOURCE_train, SOURCE_test = train_test_split(X, SOURCE, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

pls = PLSRegression(n_components=2)

pls.fit(X_train, SOURCE_train)

A, B, C = pls.coef_
```

Can I treat these coefficients the same as I would the linear regression case? I.e., do they roughly measure the relative contributions of the different drivers to the variability of my SOURCE?I would want to use the r^2 value associated with my fit as an overall measure of how much of the variability in SOURCE can be attributed to D1, D2, and D3, like:

```
SOURCE_pred = pls.predict(X_test)
r2 = r2_score(SOURCE_pred, ZZ_pred)
```

Then, I would normalize the absolute values of A B and C so that they add up to r^2

```
A_norm = (A / (A + B + C) ) * r2 #etc
```

and I would therefore have the relative contributions of D1, D2, and D3 to the variability in SOURCE.Is this a correct usage of PLS and the associated coefficients? If not, how would I use PLS to estimate the contributions of different drivers?

(I also asked this question on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/statistics/comments/19cxa9w/q_using_pls_from_sklearn_to_determine_relative/))